# Supertest with basic authorization

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, supertest

I'm trying to develop tests using supertest. The problem is all routes in my server require basic authorization. When using postman on each request I put login and password into authorization tab and choose Basic Auth.

```
  describe('correct login and password inserted', () => {
            it('should pass validation', done => {
                request(app)
                    .get('/api/roles')
                    .send({ username: 'user1', password: '1234' })
                    .expect(200)
                    .end((err, res) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return done.fail(err);
                        }
                        const roles = res.body;
                        console.log(roles);
                        expect(roles.data._id).toEqual(newRole._id);
                        expect(roles.data.name).toEqual('role_create');
                        expect(roles.data.prdPermissionsBitMask).toEqual(4);
                        expect(roles.data.userPermissionsBitMask).toEqual(4);
                        done();
                    })
            });
        });
```

This should return list of roles, but it fails with Unauthorized. Can anyone help me to bring this tests to work.

```
const request = require('supertest')
```

Comment: DId you check your credentials?

Comment: @JotaGe yes, they are correct

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [built in `auth` method that comes with SuperTest through SuperAgent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#authentication).

```
request(app)
  .get('/api/roles')
  .auth('user1', '1234')
```